# Running a git clone and rsync bash script during a docker compose build

Tags: bash, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

**docker-compose:**

```
version: '3'
services:
  php:
    build:
      context: ./
      dockerfile: ./Dockerfile
    volumes:
      - ./wordpress:/var/www/html:rw
    restart: always
```

**Dockerfile:**

```sh
FROM php:7-fpm-alpine

RUN apk add --quiet --no-cache bash git rsync

COPY ./scripts/php/install-wordpress.sh /install-wordpress.sh
RUN chmod +x /install-wordpress.sh \
  && sh /install-wordpress.sh
```

**install-wordpress.sh:**

```
#!/bin/bash

set -ex

git clone --depth=1 --no-tags https://github.com/roots/bedrock.git /tmp/bedrock

rsync -rp /tmp/bedrock/ /var/www/html/

exec "$@"
```

When I run `docker-compose build php`; `docker-compose up -d`; then `docker-compose exec php /bin/bash` and `ls` in `/var/www/html/` the directory is empty however `bedrock` has been cloned into `tmp`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Docker image should work as it supposed to work if you run it without docker-compose.
try to run

```
 docker run --rm --name testc -it your_image bash -c "ls /var/www/html/"
```

This issue is with `volumes:` it hides everything from Docker image. remove the

```
volumes:
      - ./wordpress:/var/www/html:rw
```

And it should work fine.

```
version: '3'
services:
  php:
    build:
      context: ./
      dockerfile: ./Dockerfile
      restart: always
```

**update:**

You can not view the files even if you mount the empty directory of the host, the reason is you cloned repo at build, not at run time.

To view files in host without exec in Docker you must clone at run time and you should be moved you script from to entry point. you current script `install-wordpress.sh` is not entrypoint it's just like other RUN commands of the Dockerfile.

```
FROM php:7-fpm-alpine
RUN apk add --quiet --no-cache bash git rsync
COPY install-wordpress.sh /install-wordpress.sh
RUN chmod +x /install-wordpress.sh 
entrypoint ["/install-wordpress.sh"]
CMD ["php-fpm"]
```

entrypoint.sh

```
#!/bin/bash

set -ex

git clone --depth=1 --no-tags https://github.com/roots/bedrock.git /tmp/bedrock

rsync -rp /tmp/bedrock/ /var/www/html/

exec "$@"
```

so now if you run

```
docker run --rm --name testc -v $PWD/:/var/www/html/ -it your_image
```

It should work fine and you will able to see files wordpress files also clone files and folder as well.

```
version: '3'
services:
  php:
    build:
      context: ./
      dockerfile: ./Dockerfile
    volumes:
      - ./wordpress:/var/www/html:rw
    restart: always
```

Comment: If I don't provide a volume in `docker-compose.yml` how can I see the cloned files without SSH'ing into the container? Also, I'm using compose because I plan on attaching other services to this. Usually I'd just open `/wordpress` in my editor.

Comment: you can not see files if cloned at build time. to view files you should clone it run time. otherwise if you map volume it will overide.

Comment: @AllanThomas answer is updated. you need mofiy entrypoint plus dockerfile to make it working with `wordpress` and git repo

Comment: So should I run `build php` then `up -d` then `run`?

Comment: I posted both approaches